# Tag synonym suggestion: 'business' and 'business-history'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Looking through our site's tags, I found [business](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), [buisness](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buisness), and [business-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-history). All of these tags seem to refer to the same thing.

I took the liberty of correcting the [buisness](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buisness) tag myself, since it was clearly a typo and only had one question.

What about the [business](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) and [business-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-history) tags? Should we merge or synonymize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't like the redundancy inherent in tags on this stack that end in "-history". You could do that with *every* tag. So I've taken the liberty of moving all the [business-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-history) items (one of which was a question of mine) into [business](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business).

In general, I think ending tags with "-history" on the **history** stack should be avoided.

Comment: Why would you do that through manual edits, instead of creating a synonym and merging the tags?

Comment: That's a good question. My main concern is that I dislike the "-history" tag enough that I want it to go away, which it will do if no question uses it for a while. I'm not sure if a "merge" would do that, or instead preserve the thing.

Comment: If you make it a **synonym**, then when someone makes a *new* question and tags it the business-history, it will be automatically remapped into business. If you **merge** them, then all *current* business-history question is retagged business. Manual editing does not really address the underlying issue but has the added nuisance of bumping a lot of old questions.

Comment: @Semaphore - There's still a pending operation on the two tags. ... What are we going to do with them again?

Comment: @Malandy I don't think there's anything normal users can do.